# MYSQL ALTER Can't assign foreign key (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter

I'm trying to assign a foreign key.

I have a 'users' table:

```
user_id        mediumint(8) unsigned, NotNull, Primary Key, AutoIncrement,
first_name     varchar(20)          , NotNull
last_name      varchar(40)          , NotNull
```

and cetera. And I have a 'projects' table:

```
project_id          int(10) unsigned, NotNull, Primary Key, AutoIncrement,
project_name        varchar(20)     , NotNull
user_id             mediumint(8)    , NotNull
```

And I've just learnt about foreign keys, they sound great, but I can't get them to work...

```
ALTER TABLE projects 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_projects 
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
REFERENCES users(user_id) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Returns the error message:

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'thermal.#sql-62d9_4' (errno: 150)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The problem is that two user_id columns are not the same type, in users it is "mediumint unsigned", while in projects it is just "mediumint", not being entirely sure what "unsignued" means I didn't pick up on this.

The solution is to change them:

```
ALTER TABLE projects
MODIFY COULMN user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED;
```

And then I ran my command from above, and everything worked.